# Persisting failed messages in Camel's SEDA queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, eip

I am using seda queue as dead letter channel endpoint. It works fine if network is down or other application is down.
What will happen if I restart my own system? 
Will I loose my messages in dead letter channel endpoint SEDA queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seda endpoint is not a reliable message solution, meaning any messages sent to a seda destination are subject to loss in the event of a failure/restart.  If JMS is not an available solution you will need to provide your own persistence logic to provide message recovery.

Additionally, given that seda endpoints are asynchronous, you must ensure that a pattern of message acknowledgement is used post persistence of the DLQ message so your producer to the DLQ will be notified of success or failure to ensure reliability.

This of course when using a DLQ.  You could also use a persistence preprocessor that would store messages meant for delivery and only delete them in the case of a failure to deliver them.